# sed does not work with psexec and redirect when working on large file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, command-line, psexec

I want to call `sed` upon a large file `data.csv` on a remote server `servername` and redirect the output to `data_mod.csv`. `data.csv` itself is around 1 GB. Both the local and remote machine is running on Windows.

Below is the command I used:

`psexec \\\\servername sed <somepattern> \\\\servername\\data.csv > \\\\servername\\data_mod.csv`

However, it ended up with the result that `\\\\servername\\data_mod.csv` is created but empty.

To address the issue, I also tried to run `sed <somepattern> \\\\servername\\data.csv > \\\\servername\\data_mod.csv` directly on the remote server, which worked fine.

Ironically, when I replaced `data.csv` with a small file, e.g. `head data.csv > small_data.csv`, then the command`psexec \\\\servername sed <somepattern> \\\\servername\\small_data.csv > \\\\servername\\data_mod.csv` also worked fine.

I am wondering what will the potential problem be.

Comment: Could you write a script that doe this on the remote server and then call that script via `psexec`. ALso, if running as `psexec`, and assuming the `servername` is the same in all 3 cases, could you use the local file names in your command since the context of the sed would be that same server. E.g. if `ssssvername\f1.csv` maps to `d:\dir\f1.csv`, could you specify `d:\\dir\\f1.csv` in your command?

Comment: @TenG I understand your first point. However, due to some constraint, I am not supposed to do that as I am not the owner of the remote server. I also tried `psexec \\\\servername sed <somepattern> G:\\dir\\data.csv > G:\\data_mod.csv`, but it showed 'G:\\data_mod.csv No such file or directory'. I am not sure how to fix this problem.

Comment: Can you copy the file done, run sed, then copy the output back?

Comment: @TenG The file is large and I have hundreds of this kind of files to process. The network bandwidth is the bottleneck of the whole process. That's why I am trying to use `psexec` in parallel so all can be done remotely with heavy network transferring.